# Relation symmetric and antisymmetric

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, relations

Let $A$ a non-empty set. If there is a complete relation on $A$ that is both symmetric and antisymmetric, does it imply that the relation is the "equality" and $A$ has one single element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ can consist of any number of elements, but the relation must indeed be "equality" since the relation only satisfies reflexivity.

**Antisymmetry:** For all $x,y \in A$: $xRy$ and $yRx$ imply $x=y$

**Symmetry:** For all $x,y \in A$: $xRy$ implies $yRx$.

Taking both, we conclude $xRy$ implies $x = y$.

Comment: Thank you. But if the relation is equality the elements must be all the same, right?

Comment: @mathlearner it doesn't need to be true that $xRy$ for any $x,y \in A$.  So no.

Comment: But I said it is a "complete" or "total" relation, so every two elements of the set are related.

Comment: Oh.  Well then, you're right.